# Java with looping and reading lists

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, time

I'm not an expert, just a beginner. So I kindly ask that you write some code for me.

I have four ArrayLists -> `error_list_A, list_A, error_list_B, list_B` in java.
There is a separate program running independently which add objects to these lists.

I need to write a separate program which reads them for 1 minute or until they are empty and then go to the next one. This program should always in the running mode and listening to these list and processing them.

Something like..

1. Read `error_list_A` and process its elements.

   If no elements then go to `list_A`

   If elements then read elements and remove them until all are processed or time limit of 1 minute is reached then go to `list_A`
2. Read `list_A` and process its elements.

   If no elements then go to `error_list_B`

   If elements then read elements and remove them until all are processed or time limit of 1 minute is reached then go to `error_list_B`
3. Read `error_list_B` and process its elements.

   If no elements then go to `list_B`

   If elements then read elements and remove them until all are processed or time limit of 1 minute is reached then go to `list_B`
4. read `list_B` and process its elements.

   If no elements then go to `error_list_A` (loop back to see if there are new elements in `error_list_A`)

   If elements then read elements and remove them until all are processed or time limit of 1 minute is reached then go to `error_list_A` (loop back to see if there are new elements in `error_list_A`)
5. Looping back to step 1.

Can you post some example code, please?

I know how to read and process them so you can ignore that part. Just need code for switching between lists and keeping them reading in the loop.

Its not a homework. In an actual program, I have to implement this with reading directories which are storing errors from web application. So please don't ignore it by saying you are helping in the homework.

I tried something like this..

```
public class ListReader {

    private static List<Object> list_A, error_list_A, list_B, error_list_B; // Initialize list by reading them.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            if (error_list_A != null && error_list_A.size() > 0) {
                processList(error_list_A);
            } else if (list_A != null && list_A.size() > 0) {
                processList(list_A);
            } else if (list_B != null && list_B.size() > 0) {
                processList(list_B);
            } else if (error_list_B != null && error_list_B.size() > 0) {
                processList(error_list_B);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void processList(List<Object> list){
        // Code for when empty or time limit reached then return
    }

}
```

But seems like doesn't make sense.

Thank you.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow I'm afraid.

Comment: First you try something and then show us some real problem you are facing. I am sure SO won't let you down if you show your efforts.

Comment: I don't need pure code. Just some code switching between lists and keeping them reading in the loop.

Comment: Try something, write a `main`, a simple `Thread`. Get a error. Then we could help.

Comment: @user1913599 You don't need to try and condense it all down into one loop. You can use multiple loops.

Comment: Also *Can you post some example code, please?*

Comment: the requirement given by you matches the code you wrote in main(), can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Can anybody please help where can I start or look for similar code? Any utility in java I can take a look for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you write the code yourself.In that way only, you will be learning the language.
The most difficult problem in computer science is finding a best algorithm for a problem.Implementation is easy, if you have an algorithm in hand.

So please code the algorithm and if you are facing some errors or issues in that, please post here.

update

```
 if (error_list_A != null && error_list_A.size() > 0) {
                processList(error_list_A);
            }
if (list_A != null && list_A.size() > 0) {
                processList(list_A);
            }
if (list_B != null && list_B.size() > 0) {
                processList(list_B);
            }
if (error_list_B != null && error_list_B.size() > 0) {
                processList(error_list_B);
            }
```

in the processList function , you start your timer and then start processing each element from list.Before processing each element, check the timer.If it exceeds 1 minute you can return from function, else continue.Continue this until you reach the end of list.If the time has not exceeded 1 minute yet, return.

Comment: Can you please suggest some sample code for this problem? I don't need exact code but just some hints..

Comment: Use of timer for 1 minute wait seems to be very feasible than continuous while loop.  However you can also make use of `System.currentTimeMillis()` and create exact time counter, but its a big hedache